# Strange bug when using LINQ2SQL trying to databind a repeater

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I have a strange bug when using LINQ2SQL. I try to bind a repeater with this code :

```
OrthEvalFormulaire o = oRepository.GetTable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdOrthEvalFormulaire == IdOrthEvalFormulaire);

repCategorie.DataSource = o.OrthEvalCategorie.ToList();
repCategorie.DataBind();
```

In the debugger i can see that the datasource got the single record which is supposed to get.

Once i call databind i can see that the repeater have 1 item in the count.

But when the page get showed, nothing.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lots !

Comment: What does `GetTable()` do and what does it return? What does `OrthEvalCategorie` return?

Comment: What markup have you got your repeater showing?  Are you sure it's valid - i.e have you looked at the page source to make sure it's not there, but just hidden?

Comment: @Steven and Paddy : GetTable() return the table from the context of LINQ2SQL. It does return a form. And the form contains the list of categories. That what i am trying to bind to the datasource. The markup i am showing are valid.. i also have an event called repCategorie_OnItemDataBound which affect content of the template and it return the correct data from the datasource that got binded. (So that mean the databind work) What doesnt work is that it show nothing.. like it had nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. This was a code 18. (My fault) I was binding some other datasource somewhere else to that repeater. -_- I can't believe i did this. Ouch.. 2 days to find this.